# Search for a text in Cornerstone (Mac)

Tags: svn, repository, cornerstone

is there a way to search for a certain text in all the repositories you have in your Cornerstone?
For example, i have 20 repositories. Each with different projects. I want to search for classes/projects that contain "Hello" text without going through all 20 repos and checking all the projects within it.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to index and search subversion repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493137/how-to-index-and-search-subversion-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion has no built-in mechanism for searching the contents of a *repository*. You can search the contents of your *working copy* using any desktop tools at your disposal (like Spotlight or grep).

When you say "repository" make sure you don't really mean working copy.

There are third-party products that can provide a (usually web-based) search engine for a Subversion repository. The only one that I know of offhand (but I'm certain there are others) is [FishEye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493975/1324345) but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: i don't really mean working copy.
Anyway, thanks. i guess i just have to check out some working copies and search within it. :(